# Fixing "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable" in python script

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to store some data in a config.json for a bot that I'm working on, but I keep getting the same error every time I attempt to run it.

I'm running Python 3.7.3, latest version of the rewrite. I've attempted moving around the config.json file around to no avail. I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious, but I don't know what.

Where the exception is being raised:

```py
with open("config.json", "r") as infile:
    try:
        CONFIG = json.load(infile)
        _ = infile["token"]
        _ = infile["owner"]

    except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError):
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "Your config.json file is either missing, or incomplete. Check your config.json and ensure it has the keys 'token' and 'owner_id'"
        )
```

Expected Result: Code pulls `token` and `owner` from the file, and proceeds to run the bot.

Actual Result: Bot doesn't get launched. Traceback output -

```
  File "/Users/prismarine/Desktop/Project_Prismarine/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    _ = infile["token"]
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You save json in `CONFIG`…seem like you should be looking in that for the token and owner.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call the file handle as a dictionary instead of the JSON dictionary stored in `CONFIG`. Instead, try:

```
with open("config.json", "r") as infile:
    try:
        CONFIG = json.load(infile)
        token = CONFIG["token"]
        owner = CONFIG["owner"]

    except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError):
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "Your config.json file is either missing, or incomplete. Check your config.json and ensure it has the keys 'token' and 'owner_id'"
        )
```

Note also that underscores are usually used as variable names if they won't be used anywhere, and that the underscore would be assigned to `CONFIG['token']`, then immediately reassigned to `CONFIG['owner']` in your case. I gave them some new unique variable names if you're planning to use them later.